# Init another class in construct method?

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

I am looking into trying to simplify my PHP code some more, and I have yet to find an answer with this methodology one of my team members are using. Nor, have I ever saw this done before anywhere on the web.

Here is the code example from our web application which he is working on with me.

```
<?php

class ArticlesHandler {
   public function __construct() {
      require 'Articles.php';
      $articles = new Articles;
   } 
}

?>
```

Is this proper to init one class within another class?

For me, this just seems not proper standard to init classes to work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. It works, but this particular code can lead to a number of problems.

1. You should be using `require_once` instead of `require` to avoid possible errors of including the same file twice. As it is this code here will bring your app to a complete stop:

   ```
   new ArticlesHandler;
   new ArticlesHandler;
   ```
2. This creates a hard coupling to the `Articles` class. You should *probably* rather be using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and pass an instance of `Article` to the constructor of `ArticlesHandler`. See [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is proper and normal to call constructors in a constructor. There is nothing weird/bad about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I normally do.

```
class Repository {

     protected $_models = array();

     public function getModel($model, array $params = array()){
        require_once $model.'.php'; //Replace this with an autoloader
        if(empty($this->_models[$model])){

             if(!empty($params)){
                    $this->_models[$model] = new $model($params);
             } else {
                   $this->_models[$model] = new $model();
             }

         }

        return $this->_models[$model];
     }
}
```

And call the other class like this.

```
   class ArticlesHandler extends Repository {
       public function __construct() {
          $articles = $this->getModel('Articles');
       } 
    }
```

Comment: syntax error: `if(empty($this->_models[$model)){` should be: `if(empty($this->_models[$model])){`. Can't edit your post, though :(

Comment: You're `require`ing the file *after* you instantiate the class...?!

Comment: @deceze Oops. Another mistake. Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

it seem's right.

**For me, this just seems not proper standard to init classes to work together.**

you can extend `Articles` class if you want to use `Articles` class inside the `ArticlesHandler`